# JQuery-UI and Bootstrap Conflicts

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a Rails 3.2.5 app that is using Twitter Bootstrap. I am trying to use the JQuery UI datepicker. I have Googled this for days looking for a solution and can't find anything. I have a text field in a Rails view that I am trying to use with the JQuery datepicker. However, when I click in the text field, nothing happens.

In my Rails view, I have a simple text_field_tag like so:

```
<%= text_field_tag 'andrew' %>
```

In my associated CoffeeScript file:

```
$ ->
  $('#andrew').datepicker
```

In the Chrome Developer Tools JavaScript Console, I see this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'

Now I have determined there is a conflict between JQuery-UI and Bootstrap. In that same JavaScript console, I can do this:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

and I get

```
function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)}
```

Then I can type:

```
$('andrew'.datepicker();
```

And I get:

```
[<input id="andrew" name="andrew" type="text" class="hasDatepicker">]
```

After this, when I go over to the browser window, clicking in the text field brings up the datepicker calendar just like I want it to.

So how do I get this to work in my code? That is, I am manually resolving the conflict in the JavaScript Console but I can't get it to work just through my code.

Comment: This is all the more complicated to me because I don't know CoffeeScript at all and that appears to be the default in Rails now.

Comment: Any updates on conflicts between Bootstrap 3 and jQuery UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I have this one solved after much pain. I created a new project and slowly, methodically moved over pieces of my application to the new app. I finally uncovered a directory that was only in my project with the problem described above.

There was a 'public/assets' directory with the contents below. I don't recall creating this directory or putting these files in that directory. Renaming the directory to something different caused my JQuery-UI datepicker to work properly in conjunction with Twitter Bootstrap.

Here are the contents of public/assets:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 andrunix  staff   83360 Sep  3 18:01 application 6fc1172d858485077bbecdb82b96399a.css
-rw-r--r--  1 andrunix  staff   13546 Sep  3 18:01 application-6fc1172d858485077bbecdb82b96399a.css.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 andrunix  staff  100616 Sep  3 18:01 application-990a4cf0df42934fcc4c14aaf88b7ced.js
-rw-r--r--  1 andrunix  staff   35448 Sep  3 18:01 application-990a4cf0df42934fcc4c14aaf88b7ced.js.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 andrunix  staff   83294 Sep  3 18:01 application.css
-rw-r--r--  1 andrunix  staff   13484 Sep  3 18:01 application.css.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 andrunix  staff  100618 Sep  6 20:26 application.js
-rw-r--r--  1 andrunix  staff   35448 Sep  3 18:01 application.js.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 andrunix  staff   13826 Aug 30 17:42 glyphicons-halflings-f6675c325532ec11a984d58e172b8e2a.png
-rw-r--r--  1 andrunix  staff    8777 Aug 30 17:42 glyphicons-halflings-white-13553a5bf21ae3cc374006592488ec64.png
-rw-r--r--  1 andrunix  staff    8777 Aug 30 17:42 glyphicons-halflings-white.png
-rw-r--r--  1 andrunix  staff   13826 Aug 30 17:42 glyphicons-halflings.png
-rw-r--r--  1 andrunix  staff     368 Sep  5 15:00 manifest.yml
-rw-r--r--  1 andrunix  staff    6646 Aug 10 19:57 rails-be8732dac73d845ac5b142c8fb5f9fb0.png
-rw-r--r--  1 andrunix  staff    6646 Aug 10 19:57 rails.png
```

If anyone knows how this got created, that would put my mind at ease. Thanks!

Andrew

Comment: Oh, and I know how this got created. bundle exec rake assets:precompile